# Reverse Engineer Talend Jobs

Tags: talend

We have a set of Talend Jobs running in production, which were created many years ago and the developer is no longer with the company. However, the source code for the jobs is missing - only have the compiled jar files.

Is there a way to reverse engineer the jobs from the jar file? If I de-compile the jar file, can I import them/open them in Talend? Don't want to re-build these jobs since we are re-engineering the entire project, but need to update them since have to migrate servers.

Any thoughts/ideas will greatly be appreciated.

Thanks,
Bee

Comment: Do you still have the system available to you where the Talend jobs were initially created?  Perhaps the Talend workspace is still intact.

Comment: Thank you @tale852150 for responding. Unfortunately, the workspace is corrupted. So hoping for a way to reverse engineer the jobs from jar file.

Comment: Any backups of that system where the workspace is intact?

Comment: None. it was an old desktop. We do have versions of the workspace though but they are old and chances are the code base doesnt match what is running in production.

Comment: Well, those old workspaces are better than none. :-)  I'd restore those and see what you have.

Answer (score 2):

When you build a Talend job, it creates a zip file which contains the compiled code, necessary jar files, and usually a copy of the job definitions (this is effectively a copy of the original project and your source code).

Find where the job is deployed.  Look inside the job's folder. if you have a job named "example_job", you'll likely have a folder structure in there that looks like this

```
example_job
* lib
* example_job
** items
*** example_job  (Look in this folder. it contains the original project)
** example_job
** src
```

Comment: Hello @dbh thanks for your message. So, if I import this project to another workspace, I should be able to restore the workspace/jobs? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No guarantees but yes. If the job was exported with source, and you have that folder, you should be able to retrieve it and import into Talend open studio for data integration .